# Pass content of file in variable into bash script - without writing the file down

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a bash script like

```
./script -a filename
```

And I have the content of a file in a variable $CONTENT

How can I pass the variable into the command. I mean I could write the content of the variable down to disk first, but that seems to be too much overhead.

Is there a better solution?

Something like

```
./scrip -a << $CONTENT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need one more `<`:

```
./script -a <<<"$CONTENT"
```

`<<<` is called a herestring, and takes the following string and passes it as the standard input.

Comment: You should use quotes: `./script -a <<< "$CONTENT"`

Comment: You must be joking, and it's not funny! Try: `s="a   b"` (with, say, three spaces between a and b, it doesn't show properly here), then compare `cat <<< $s` and `cat <<< "$s"`. Also, please refer to the [Here String](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) section of the manual. You'll read: _The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input_. Yes, **is expanded**. As a general rule: _Use More Quotes!_

Comment: I see, the spaces are collapsed. It doesn't expand into other arguments though, which is what I had tested.

Comment: Expansion for unquoted variables can have side effects, e.g., if you set funny `IFS`, etc. so better always quote!

Comment: I was trying to use that with `xsltproc <<< "$xslt_content" "$xml_path"` and `file <<< "$content"`. None of those worked. Does it have to be the last argument? What's wrong with the `file` call?

Answer (score 4):

Kevin's suggestion to use a here string will work, as long as you quote the variable as suggested in the comments to that answer.  A more portable solution is to use a here doc:

```
./script -a << EOF
$CONTENT
EOF
```

In this case, quotes are not necessary and indeed undesirable.